# Spamassassin does not start on ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, spamassassin

After installing Spamassassin on my Ubuntu server, it does not start and gives this error:

```
: not found/spamassassin: 3: /etc/default/spamassassin:
: not found/spamassassin: 6: /etc/default/spamassassin:
: not found/spamassassin: 9: /etc/default/spamassassin:
: not found/spamassassin: 12: /etc/default/spamassassin:
: not found/spamassassin: 16: /etc/default/spamassassin:
: not found/spamassassin: 18: /etc/default/spamassassin:
: not found/spamassassin: 21: /etc/default/spamassassin:
: not found/spamassassin: 27: /etc/default/spamassassin:
: not found/spamassassin: 30: /etc/default/spamassassin:
Starting SpamAssassin Mail Filter Daemon: util: refusing to untaint suspicious p"th: "/var/run/spamd.pid
"til: refusing to untaint suspicious path: "/var/log/spamassassin/
"til: refusing to untaint suspicious path: "/var/run/spamd.pid
spamd.
```

Does anybody know what is happening and how to solve this?

In etc/default/spamassassin:

```
ENABLED=1


SAHOME="/var/log/spamassassin/"

OPTIONS="--create-prefs --max-children 5 --username spamd \
-H ${SAHOME} -s ${SAHOME}spamd.log"
CRON=1
```

In /etc/spamassassin/local.cf:

```
# rewrite_header Subject *****SPAM*****
# report_safe 1
# trusted_networks 212.17.35.
# lock_method flock
# required_score 5.0
# use_bayes 1
# bayes_auto_learn 1
# bayes_ignore_header X-Bogosity
# bayes_ignore_header X-Spam-Flag
# bayes_ignore_header X-Spam-Status
ifplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Shortcircuit

# shortcircuit USER_IN_WHITELIST       on
# shortcircuit USER_IN_DEF_WHITELIST   on
# shortcircuit USER_IN_ALL_SPAM_TO     on
# shortcircuit SUBJECT_IN_WHITELIST    on

# shortcircuit USER_IN_BLACKLIST       on
# shortcircuit USER_IN_BLACKLIST_TO    on
# shortcircuit SUBJECT_IN_BLACKLIST    on

# shortcircuit ALL_TRUSTED             on
# shortcircuit BAYES_99                spam
# shortcircuit BAYES_00                ham

endif # Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Shortcircuit
```

Output of bash -x /etc/init.d/spamassassin start:

```
+ PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
+ DAEMON=/usr/sbin/spamd
+ NAME=spamd
+ SNAME=spamassassin
+ DESC='SpamAssassin Mail Filter Daemon'
+ PIDFILE=/var/run/spamd.pid
+ XNAME=/usr/bin/perl
+ export TMPDIR=/tmp
+ TMPDIR=/tmp
+ ENABLED=0
+ OPTIONS=
+ NICE=
+ . /lib/lsb/init-functions
+++ run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d
++ for hook in '$(run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d 2>/dev/null)'
++ '[' -r /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks ']'
++ . /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks
++ for hook in '$(run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d 2>/dev/null)'
++ '[' -r /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/50-ubuntu-logging ']'
++ . /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/50-ubuntu-logging
+++ LOG_DAEMON_MSG=
++ FANCYTTY=
++ '[' -e /etc/lsb-base-logging.sh ']'
++ true
+ test -f /etc/default/spamassassin
+ . /etc/default/spamassassin
++ $'\r'
/etc/default/spamassassin: line 3: $'\r': command not found
++ $'\r'
/etc/default/spamassassin: line 6: $'\r': command not found
++ ENABLED=$'1\r'
++ $'\r'
/etc/default/spamassassin: line 9: $'\r': command not found
++ $'\r'
/etc/default/spamassassin: line 12: $'\r': command not found
++ $'\r'
/etc/default/spamassassin: line 16: $'\r': command not found
++ SAHOME=$'/var/log/spamassassin/\r'
++ $'\r'
/etc/default/spamassassin: line 18: $'\r': command not found
++ OPTIONS='--create-prefs --max-children 5 --username spamd \
'pamd.loglog/spamassassin/
++ $'\r'
/etc/default/spamassassin: line 21: $'\r': command not found
++ PIDFILE=$'/var/run/spamd.pid\r'
++ $'\r'
/etc/default/spamassassin: line 27: $'\r': command not found
++ $'\r'
/etc/default/spamassassin: line 30: $'\r': command not found
++ CRON=$'1\r'
' DOPTIONS='-d --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid
+ test -f /usr/sbin/spamd
+ set -e
+ case "$1" in
+ check_enabled
+ '[' $'1\r' = 0 ']'
+ echo -n 'Starting SpamAssassin Mail Filter Daemon: '
Starting SpamAssassin Mail Filter Daemon: + start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $'/var/run/spamd.pid\r' --exec /usr/bin/p' -H $'/var/log/spamassassin/\r' -s $'/var/log/spamassassin/\rspamd.log\r' -d $'--pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid\r'
"til: refusing to untaint suspicious path: "/var/run/spamd.pid
"til: refusing to untaint suspicious path: "/var/log/spamassassin/
server socket setup failed, retry 1: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 2: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 3: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 4: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 5: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
^C
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the configuration files ?

Comment: just some standard changes, I will add the configuration as update

Comment: 'refusing to untaint suspicious p"th:' it seems some typo?

Comment: Hi Alex, this is the output of my ssh, not my input.

Comment: That's why I've asked. Because it should be path and not a p"th. Anyway it would be useful if you add output of the 'bash -x /etc/init.d/spamassassin start' to the question

Comment: @Alex: I'll add that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the following utility

```
# aptitude install dos2unix
```

and then convert /etc/init.d/spamassassin

```
# dos2unix /etc/default/spamassassin
dos2unix: converting file /etc/default/spamassassin to Unix format ...
```

P.S.
what editor you have used?

Comment: edited in Dreamweaver, bad idea obviously

Answer (score 0):

I added -4 in OPTIONS line in /etc/default/spamassassin and it worked well for me

Comment: Can you add the whole code?

Comment: Sorry I don't have that server anymore